# How can i get notifications from server to android device?

Tags: android, servlets, webserver

I am creating a app wherein user shares some information. This data i am storing it in database through servlets i.e. i am calling my own servlets which will take data through url and store it in database. So i want other users of that same app to get notify that some information is available and in turn they will get the information that other user has updated. 
For this to work we can use polling or pusher. But polling will take lots of battery power.
I have tried C2DM but its not working for me. So i am thinking for some other mechanism by which i can implement other than C2DM. 
Please suggest some way to work it. and e.g. if u have came across.

Comment: Did you try [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C2DM is deprecated, the new version is called [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM) and is exactly what you need for your use case. There is even a [GCM Demo Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) which uses a Java servlet. The source code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/), you [browse it directly](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/) or if you prefer GitHub you can use [this repository](https://github.com/ketanpatel25/GCM-Demo).

The servlet code can be found in the file

```
samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/HomeServlet.java
```

If you follow the instructions in the [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) guide you will soon have a working application. I would suggest you not trying to copy paste it together, you have to get a clear understanding of how the GCM architecture is working.

Comment: sorry but i cant find The source code for it at a mentioned Link.

Comment: @Vaibs I have added more links to my question you should find it now. By the way on Google hosted code projects you can browse the code by going to *Source* and then selecting *Browse* from the navigation holding *Checkout* *Browse* *Changes* *Clones*